# How to define list of user claims for OIDC /userinfo request

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I have a custom UserStoreManager running in WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 as secondary user store.
It perfectly works for authenticating users.
When using it with an OpenID Connect authentication the expected claims are not returned to the client in the response of the `/userinfo?schema=openid` request.
Logging in the custom UserStoreManager reveals that method getUserPropertyValues() gets invoked with the following claim names:

```
["postalcode", "mail", "localityName", "sn", "cn", "nickName", "telephoneNumber", "gender", "givenName", "url", "country"]
```

The response to `/userinfo` request actually returns only claims from that list. It is not possible get other claims being returned.

What I don't understand is where this list comes from. The configured claim mapping for "http://wso2.org/oidc/claim" defines for example "postalcode" as "Supported by Default=false" and "Required=false".
So I don't expect it to be in the list. On the other hand claim "sub" (or the name it is mapped to: "uid") is not in the list, but its definition in dialect "http://wso2.org/oidc/claim" is

- Claim Uri: sub
- Mapped Attribute (s): uid
- Supported by Default: true
- Required: **true**

Furthermore "sub" is a required claim by the definition of OIDC Spec (see http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfoResponse).

Where can the list of claims be defined that should be returned by a /userinfo?schema=openid request for a successfully authenticated user?

Answer (score 2):

Invoking userinfo endpoint we get the users attribute values for the claims listed under http://wso2.com/oidc/claim dialect.

In claim configurations we have claim uri and particular attribute in user store (Primary and default value for secondary user stores).
Ex : http://wso2.org/oidc/claim/sub and its mapped attribute is uid

If secondary user store does not support for this default attribute value we have to configure it under mapped attribute.
Ex :

```
 secondary user store domain = SECONDARY_
 supported attribute value fore sub = subject
 Configuration for mapped attribute = uid;SECONDARY_/subject
```

Now you will get the correct attribute value list to getUserPropertyValues()  method.

Following configurations are used in admin console profile management

Supported by Default = true
In admin console this attributes is available to edit by default
Required=true
This attribute must filed when you updated user profile.